# How can I get rid of Twitter’s “Let’s Get Started” Box?

Tags: twitter

So when you sign up for Twitter, it has a checklist of things you're supposed to do. I've done all of them, except download the mobile app (because I don't have a smartphone). How can I get rid of the box without downloading the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to click on it and open the app's webpage, it doesn't actually check if you've installed it.